# Planck Blackbody Radiation: Is this an error in the textbook?

Tags: conventions, thermal-radiation, differentiation, textbook-erratum

the textbook I am reading describes two forms of equations of Blackbody Radiation.
$$d\rho(\nu, T) = d\rho_\nu(T)d\nu = \frac{8\pi h}{c^3}\ \frac{\nu^3d\nu}{e^{h\nu/k_BT}-1}\ . $$

Substituting $ c = \nu\lambda  $  and $ d\nu = -\frac{c}{\lambda^2} d\lambda $,

$$d\rho(\lambda, T) = d\rho_\lambda(T)d\lambda = \frac{8\pi h c}{\lambda^5}\ \frac{d\lambda}{e^{hc/k_BT\lambda}-1}\ . $$

However, since $$ d\nu = -\frac{c}{\lambda^2} d\lambda ,$$ shouldn't there be negative sign in the right most term in the second equation? Is this just a typo in the textbook? Because according to the second equation, an increase in wavelength would lead to an increase in $d\rho$, which contradicts that $d\rho$ increases when frequency increases.

Comment: These equations describe what happens to $d\rho$ when you increase the wavelength or frequency _or_ the wavelength/frequency _bandwidths_ (described in the small-width limit by $d\nu$ and $d\lambda$). Whether you're talking about wavelength or frequency, increasing the bandwidth will increase the spectral density. It's true that, _for a given bandwidth_, increasing the wavelength, for sufficiently large wavelengths, will decrease the spectral density, but this is reflected by the $\frac{1}{\lambda^5}$ term.

Answer (score 0):

If you plot the two functions, the one in terms of $\lambda$ and the one in terms of $\nu$, you will obtain two similar curves, a single peaked one. But the x-axis is actually reversed: the left side of the curve from the peak for the $\lambda$ graph corresponds to the right side of the peak for the $\nu$ side. Let us say you are on the left of the peak for the  $\nu$ curve. A given $d\nu$ will result in an increase in the radiation. But a corresponding  $d\lambda$ will produce a decrease of radiation, because now you are at the right of the peak.